# Why is there such a problem with finding a formula for the general term of a sequence?

Tags: sequence

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 5, 14, 41}, n]

1/6 (3 + 3^n)
```

You can directly calculate the general term formula above

Why is it impossible to find the general term formula below?

```
In[1]:= FindSequenceFunction[{2^1, 2^2, 2^5, 2^14, 2^41}, n]

Out[1]= FindSequenceFunction[{2, 4, 32, 16384, 2199023255552}, n]
```

The result should be:

```
2^(1/6 (3 + 3^n))
```

Comment: Seems like it wasn't such a problem, and certainly not impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround:

```
seq = Log@{2^1, 2^2, 2^5, 2^14, 2^41}

FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] // FullSimplify // Exp
```

> 2^(1/6 (3 + 3^n))